# C++: Program not outputting function return value

Tags: c++

I can't figure out why the return value form the "deleteEntry" function is not being output in the last part of my program. It jumps from "Now your list has 5 names again!" to asking if you want to do it again without showing the list without the name you asked it to delete. I know it did it correctly when I tried earlier, but I'm not sure if I changed something without paying attention or if I'm doing something that makes the program do things randomly.

Here's the source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int search(string* dynamicArray, int size, string entrytoDelete);

string* addEntry(string *dynamicArray, int&size, string newEntry);

string* deleteEntry(string *dynamicArray, int &size, string entrytoDelete);

int main()
{
  char answer;

  do
    {

      string* name;
      string name2;
      int size = 5;
      int x;
      name = new string[5];

      cout << "\nEnter 5 names:\n";
      for(x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
      getline(cin, name[x]);
    }
      cout << endl;
      cout << "You entered: \n";
      for(x = 0; x< size; x++)
    {
      cout << *(name + x) << endl;
    }

      cout << "\nEnter another name: \n";
      getline(cin, name2);
      name = addEntry(name, size, name2);
      cout << "\nYour list now has an extra name!\n";
      for(x = 0; x < size; x++)
    cout << x << ": " << name[x] << endl;

      cout<< "\nPick one name to delete: \n";
      getline(cin, name2);
      name = deleteEntry(name, size, name2);
      cout << "\nNow your list has 5 names again!\n";
      for(x = 0; x < size; x++)
    cout << x << ": " << name[x] << endl;

      cout << "\nWould you like to try again? (Y/N)\n";
      cin >> answer;
    }while(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y');

  cout << "Goodbye.\n";

  return 0;
}


string* addEntry(string *dynamicArray, int&size, string newEntry)
{ 
  string *new_Large = new string[size + 1];

  for(int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
      new_Large[x] = *(dynamicArray + x);
    }

  new_Large[size] = newEntry;
  size++;

  delete [] dynamicArray;


  return new_Large;
}

string* deleteEntry(string *dynamicArray, int &size, string entrytoDelete)
{
  int toDelete;
  toDelete = search(dynamicArray, size, entrytoDelete);

  if(toDelete >= 0)
    {
      string *new_Small = new string[size - 1];

      for(int x = 0; x < (size - 1); x++)
    {
      new_Small[x] = *(dynamicArray + x);
      if(dynamicArray[x] != entrytoDelete)
         new_Small[x] = dynamicArray[x];
    }
      size -= size;
      return new_Small;
    }
  else 
    {
      cout << entrytoDelete << " does not exist.\n";
      return dynamicArray;
    }
}

int search(string* dynamicArray, int size, string entrytoDelete)
{
  int toDelete = -1;
  for(int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
      if(*(dynamicArray + x) == entrytoDelete)
    {
      toDelete = x;
    }
    }
      return toDelete;
}
```

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Unrelated to your question you have a memory leak in your program, when you return the new dynamic array to assign to `name`

Comment: Why resort to doing this type of coding when you could just use `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: @Bluasul, you could do all manipulation in one string, separating them by /n, so you could stay away from dynamic allocations on your part.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The program is supposed to make dynamic arrays emulate vectors.

Comment: @Bluasul So the question is this:  why are you trying to emulate vector?   Just use it -- you still need to write the code to delete entries, regardless (it's not as if the code writes itself just because you use `vector`).  In addition, trying to emulate vector is not trivial -- why not just write a vector **class**, and not just issue `new[]` and `delete[]` calls strewn throughout?

Comment: Also, you don't need to allocate again to remove an entry.  Just copy all of the entries "up" so that you overwrite the name you want to delete.  Then decrement size.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, man. Believe me, I'd be using vectors if I could, but the problem specifically asks to make dynamic arrays act like vectors.

Comment: @bkVnet Memory leak? Could you explain a little more? I've been programming for about a month and still unfamiliar with a lot of things.

Comment: @Bluasul  *I've been programming for about a month*  -- I wish that [C++ was  being taught instead of C](http://cppcast.com/2015/10/kate-gregory/).  So after a month, the goal is to get you to never use C++ again?  No beginner code should be doing this exercise, as it is first not trivial, and second, it gives the person a false sense of satisfaction if they get a "good grade" on something that is subpar or worse, really full of bugs.

Comment: @Bluasul You first assign `name` to point to a memory block you allocate in you main function,then later on you reassign 'name` to point to a different memory block allocated in and returned from your `deleteEntry` function without releasing the previous memory block pointed by `name`. That is called a memory leak. So every memory block you allocate with `new`, you should release with the corresponding  `delete` after you no longer need that memory block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other mentioned, this code has memory leaks. I can see many flaws in the code. But, to suggest a small change to produce what you want, you may start with the following changes. See the comments in the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int search(string* dynamicArray, int size, string entrytoDelete);

string* addEntry(string *dynamicArray, int&size, string newEntry);

string* deleteEntry(string *dynamicArray, int &size, string entrytoDelete);

int main()
{
  char answer;

  do
    {

      string* name;
      string name2;
      int size = 5;
      int x;
      name = new string[5];

      cout << "\nEnter 5 names:\n";
      for(x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
      getline(cin, name[x]);
    }
      cout << endl;
      cout << "You entered: \n";
      for(x = 0; x< size; x++)
    {
      cout << *(name + x) << endl;
    }

      cout << "\nEnter another name: \n";
      getline(cin, name2);
      name = addEntry(name, size, name2);
      cout << "\nYour list now has an extra name!\n";
      for(x = 0; x < size; x++)
    cout << x << ": " << name[x] << endl;

      cout<< "\nPick one name to delete: \n";
      getline(cin, name2);
      name = deleteEntry(name, size, name2);
      cout << "\nNow your list has 5 names again!\n";
      for(x = 0; x < size; x++)
    cout << x << ": " << name[x] << endl;

      cout << "\nWould you like to try again? (Y/N)\n";
      cin >> answer;
    }while(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y');

  cout << "Goodbye.\n";

  return 0;
}


string* addEntry(string *dynamicArray, int&size, string newEntry)
{ 
  string *new_Large = new string[size + 1];

  for(int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
      new_Large[x] = *(dynamicArray + x);
    }

  new_Large[size] = newEntry;
  size++;

  delete [] dynamicArray;


  return new_Large;
}

string* deleteEntry(string *dynamicArray, int &size, string entrytoDelete)
{
  int toDelete;
  toDelete = search(dynamicArray, size, entrytoDelete);

  if(toDelete >= 0)
    {
      string *new_Small = new string[size - 1];

      for(int x = 0, y = 0; x < size; x++)   //<- start of changes
    {                                        //
      // new_Small[x] = *(dynamicArray + x); //<- remove this
      if(dynamicArray[x] != entrytoDelete)   //
         new_Small[y++] = dynamicArray[x];   //<- x to y++
    }                                        //
      --size;                                //<- end of changes
      return new_Small;
    }
  else 
    {
      cout << entrytoDelete << " does not exist.\n";
      return dynamicArray;
    }
}

int search(string* dynamicArray, int size, string entrytoDelete)
{
  int toDelete = -1;
  for(int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
      if(*(dynamicArray + x) == entrytoDelete)
    {
      toDelete = x;
    }
    }
      return toDelete;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your deleteEntry:

```
size -= size;
```

This will always set size = 0.  I think you're looking to do:

```
size--;
```